# Get children of node

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm coding in Java and I'm using neo4j db.
How to find, using java code, children of node?
For instance, it's my graph:

```
[D] -> [A]
[A] -> [B]
[A] -> [C]
```

and I want to get [B] and [C] nodes starting from A node.

-> - means the same relationship...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you like to use Java API to achieve this, or would you like to use Cypher? Gremlin?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java API this would look like:

```
Node a = ....;
Collection<Node> children = new HashSet<Node>();
for (Relationship r: a.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING) {
   children.add(r.getEndNode());
}
```

`getRelationships` might also filter for relationship type, see http://api.neo4j.org/1.9/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html.